# Select distinct records using SQL from Excel

Tags: sql, excel-2007

Table in Excel columns:

```
UID ID      StartDate     Time                              Name        
1    1       1/1/2012    5:51:12                            testA       
2    2       2/2/2012    5:51:12                            testB       
3    1       1/1/2012   10:51:12                            testA       
4    2       2/2/2012   10:51:12                            testB
```

Results table target:

```
UID ID      StartDate   StartTme    EndDate     EndTime     Name
1    1       1/1/2012    5:51:12    1/1/2012    10:51:12    testA
3    2       2/2/2012    5:51:12    2/2/2012    10:51:12    testB
```

Using SQL query and reading from Excel columns how do I take the records (StartDate, Time) by matching IDs appearing a second time, and insert these as new columns 'End Date', 'EndTime' by date in ascending order?

Comment: err... what is those results?  I don't see an UID 3 with start date 2/2/12, also there is no record with name tesB

Comment: Can you better explain what each column is in the target table?

Comment: hope am able to explain this time! any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it will work:

```
SELECT
    UID = A.UID,
    ID = A.ID,
    StartDate = A.StartDate,
    StartTime = A.[Time],
    EndDate = B.StartDate,
    EndTime = B.[Time],
    Name = A.[Name]
FROM
    ExcelTable A
    JOIN ExcelTable B ON A.Id = B.ID 
ORDER BY
    A.StartDate,
    A,[Time]
```